# Return true when numbers in array match counter (Angular js + jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Currently v.currentTime returns the current time of a video when the video is played (resource: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/11/syncing-content-with-html5-video/)

I also am ng-repeating items each with a start time and end time.

The goal it to only show the object when the time of the object matches the time of the movie (ie a counter).

ps. pardon the sloppiness in a time crunch

*Javascript*

```
angular.module('MixFliks.controllers', ['firebase'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $firebase) {

  // Movies Table
  var moviesRef = new Firebase("https://mixfliks.firebaseio.com/movies");
  var sync = $firebase(moviesRef);
  $scope.movies = sync.$asArray();

  // Timeline Table
  var eventsRef = new Firebase("https://mixfliks.firebaseio.com/timeline/events");
  var sync = $firebase(eventsRef);
  $scope.events = sync.$asArray();

  // Filter out titleTypes
  $scope.filterBy = "Speaking";

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };
})

// topMixes Controller
.controller('topMixesCtrl', function($scope, $ionicNavBarDelegate, $firebase) {
  // This will remove the back button on anything in this controller
  // $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);

  $scope.upVote = function(movie, upScore) {
    var movieScore = $scope.movies[movie.$id].upVotes
    console.log(movieScore);
    movieScore.set({
      upVotes: (upScore + 1)
    });
  }

  $scope.downVote = function(movie, dwnScore) {
    var movieScore = $scope.movies[movie.$id].downVotes
    $scope.moviesRef.child(movie).set({
      downVotes: (dwnScore + 1)
    });
  }

})

.controller('recordCtrl', function($scope, $ionicNavBarDelegate, $firebase) {

// Show Video Time when video played
  (function(){
    var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var t = document.getElementById('time');
    v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(event){
      t.innerHTML = v.currentTime;

      var times = $(".test").map(function(){return $(this).data("time");});

      var time = +v.currentTime.toFixed(3);

      console.log($.inArray(time, times));

      if ($.inArray(time, times) == 0) {
        console.log("hello");
        $('.test[data-id='+time+']').show();
      }

    },false);
  })();


});
```

*html*

```
<ion-view title="Record">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-list>

        <div class="item item-body">
          <video  width="360px" src="img/Furious7.mp4" controls></video>
          <div class="time-container">
            Video Time: <div id="time">0.0</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-outline">
          <div class="record-btn ion-mic-a"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="test" ng-repeat="event in events | filter:filterBy" data-time="{{event.in/1000}}">

            <!-- TITLE TYPE -->
          <div class="title-type">
            {{event.card.object.title}}
          </div>

          <!-- CHARACTER NAME (API) -->
          <div class="role-type">
            {{event.card.object.role}}
          </div>

          <!-- CHARACTER DIALOGUE -->
          <div class="chat-dialogue">
            {{event.card.object.subtitle}}
          </div>

          <!-- MILLISECONDS IN -->
          <div class="milli-in">
            {{event.in/1000}}
          </div>

          <!-- MILLISECONDS OUT -->
          <div class="milli-out">
            {{event.out/1000}}
          </div>

          <br />

        </div>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```